# Regular expression to extract all text after "--!!" in R dplyr

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr in R to extract substrings after a variable string in a dataframe filtered by certain instances of the variable `name` in the example below. I am trying to pass the desired result into a new variable called `income_rent`.

I am new to regular expressions. My attempt to do this is:

```
income_cashrent <- v18 %>% 
filter(str_detect(name, "B25122")) %>% 
mutate(income_rent = str_extract(label, "[^--!!]*$"))
```

However, I get the result:
`Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)`

The first four lines of `name` are:

```
Estimate!!Total
Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000
Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000!!With cash rent
Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000!!With cash rent!!Less than $100
```

The desired result would be:

```
[not sure how to indicate an empty result here]
Less than $10,000
Less than $10,000!!With cash rent
Less than $10,000!!With cash rent!!Less than $100
```

I have been thus far unable to debug this, consulting other regex examples on stack. Any guidance would be most welcome. Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract to extract the characters after the pattern`--!!` using regex lookaround

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
 v18 %>%        
     mutate(income_rent = str_extract(label, "(?<=--!!).*"))                                                                                                                                                label
#1                                                                                                                                    Estimate!!Total
#2                                 Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000
#3                 Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000!!With cash rent
#4 Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000!!With cash rent!!Less than $100
 #                                       income_rent
#1                                              <NA>
#2                                 Less than $10,000
#3                 Less than $10,000!!With cash rent
#4 Less than $10,000!!With cash rent!!Less than $100
```

Or another option is `str_match`

```
v18$income_rent <-  str_match(v18$label, ".*--!!(.*)")[,2]
```

### data

```
v18 <- structure(list(label = c("Estimate!!Total", "Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000", 
"Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000!!With cash rent", 
"Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000!!With cash rent!!Less than $100"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I should have been more specific in my data sample however: not all entries in the source variable will have that "Less than" string after the "--!!". I need to get anything that comes after the "--!!", so this solution will not work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: @AbeBarranca in that case, just change it to regex lookaround.  Updated.  thanks

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks, akrun! As I said, I'm new to regex, so wasn't aware of how lookaround worked. This is super useful.

Comment: @AbeBarranca thanks, I also updated with `str_match` so that it can directly extract the elements instead of  using regex lookaround

Comment: Interesting about the ```str_match``` solution. Can you advise what the ```[,2]``` indexing does at the end of the solution?

Comment: @AbeBarranca `str_match` returns a `matrix`.  Here there are two columns.  To subset only the second column, used `[,2]`

Answer (score 4):

```r
regmatches(vec, gregexpr("(?<=--!!).*", vec, perl = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# character(0)
# [[2]]
# [1] "Less than $10,000"
# [[3]]
# [1] "Less than $10,000!!With cash rent"
# [[4]]
# [1] "Less than $10,000!!With cash rent!!Less than $100"
```

If you `unlist` from here, you'll notice that you "lose" the first entry, not sure if that's a problem.

```r
unlist(regmatches(vec, gregexpr("(?<=--!!).*", vec, perl = TRUE)))
# [1] "Less than $10,000"                                
# [2] "Less than $10,000!!With cash rent"                
# [3] "Less than $10,000!!With cash rent!!Less than $100"
```

If that's a problem, then

```r
vecout <- regmatches(vec, gregexpr("(?<=--!!).*", vec, perl = TRUE))
unlist(replace(vecout, lengths(vecout) < 1, NA))
# [1] NA                                                 
# [2] "Less than $10,000"                                
# [3] "Less than $10,000!!With cash rent"                
# [4] "Less than $10,000!!With cash rent!!Less than $100"
```

(Or you could replace with `""` as well.)

---

In a `dplyr` pipeline:

```r
tibble(vec = c("Estimate!!Total",
# "Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000",
# "Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000!!With cash rent",
# "Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000!!With cash rent!!Less than $100")) %>%
  mutate(out = regmatches(vec, gregexpr("(?<=--!!).*", vec, perl = TRUE)), out = replace(out, lengths(vecout) < 1, NA), out = unlist(out))
+ + # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   vec                                             out                           
#   <chr>                                           <chr>                         
# 1 Estimate!!Total                                 <NA>                          
# 2 Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past ~ Less than $10,000             
# 3 Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past ~ Less than $10,000!!With cash ~
# 4 Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past ~ Less than $10,000!!With cash ~
```

---

Data:

```r
vec <- c("Estimate!!Total",
"Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000",
"Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000!!With cash rent",
"Estimate!!Total!!Household income in the past 12 months (in 2018 inflation-adjusted dollars) --!!Less than $10,000!!With cash rent!!Less than $100")
```

Comment: This works well on its own, but I haven't managed to get it to work with the filtering condition before it. Not sure if it can't be nested within a dplyr pipe. Tried ```regmatches(v18[which(str_detect(v18$name, "B25122"))], gregexpr("(?<=--!!).*", v18, perl = TRUE))``` but that threw an error.

Comment: see my edit, it's exactly the code for a column as it is for a standalone vector, not sure what you were doing differently.